# AWK script returns 0 records

Tags: linux, awk, gawk

If I execute

```
echo "abcd" | awk '{print NR}'
```

returns 1, which is good.

But if I create a script file `script.awk` with the content:

```
BEGIN{print NR}
```

and execute

```
echo "abcd" | awk -f script.awk
```

returns 0.

Why?

Comment: @fedorqui Must be begin, or it would return nothing. Also OP, it returns 0 because NR is the current record number, which is zero when the script begins, try using END instead.

Comment: @123 Using END worked. Thanks

Comment: @Chris No problem. I would advise reading the man page or basic tutorials so you actually know what the variables you are using do.

Comment: Get the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins, otherwise you're going to waste a lot of time spinning your wheels on stuff like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are checking the number of records in the `BEGIN` block and this is not going to work.

Why? Because when in the `BEGIN` block, the file is not loaded yet, neither the standard input.

Instead, print it in the `END` block.

```
$ cat a.wk                 
END {print NR}
$ echo "abcd" | awk -f a.wk
1
```

From `man awk`:

> Gawk  executes AWK programs in the following order.  First, all
>   variable assignments specified via the -v option are performed.  Next,
>   gawk compiles the program into an internal form.  Then, gawk executes
>   the code in the  BEGIN  rule(s)  (if any), and then proceeds to read
>   each file named in the ARGV array (up to ARGV[ARGC]).  If there are no
>   files named on the command line, gawk reads the standard input.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` programs follow this scheme:

```
CONDITION { ACTION(S) } NEXT_CONDITION { ACTION(s) }
```

You can omit `ACTION(S)`. In that case `awk` will simply print the current record.

`BEGIN` is just a special condition which is true *before* awk starts to read the input. FYI, there is also an `END` condition which is true *after* awk has been processed all lines of input.

There is no difference in they syntax of commanline scripts and scripts put into a file.

---

Conclusion:

You can simply put this into your script:

*test.awk*

```
{print NR}
```

and call it like:

```
awk -f test.awk <<< 'hello'
```

Comment: Yep! In this case, it will print as many numbers (from 1 to...) as lines the file has